# anything wrong with the android XML file?

Tags: android, xml

I have been looking for the error for a long time, but cannot find it. i have marked the error in the code below. can anybody explain it?

```
    <TableLayout 
        android:id = "@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content>

        <TableRow>          <==Here eclipse marks an error
            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_widht = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:text = "User:" />
            <EditText
                android:id = "@+id/EditText01"
                android:text = "admin"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I got errors:

```
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:/home/lubuntu/workspace/MainListener/bin/resources.ap_ does not exist
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
The value of attribute "android:layout_height" associated with an element type "TableLayout" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you the problem pretty accurately:

`The value of attribute "android:layout_height" associated with an element type "TableLayout" must not contain the '<' character.`

If you look, you can see there is a missing quotation:

```
   <TableLayout 
        android:id = "@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content>  <==== MISSING A QUOTE!

        <TableRow>          <==Here eclipse marks an error
            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_widht = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:text = "User:" />
            <EditText
                android:id = "@+id/EditText01"
                android:text = "admin"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Oops, i only noticed the `'<' character` in error. There is also an error on the spelling of "width", now everything goes well, thx

Comment: @MarkZar Happens to all of us sometimes. :)